# What is QTCaptureScreenInput?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, qtkit

On a screen-recording github project [here](https://github.com/onedanshow/Mac-Screen-Recorder/blob/master/ScreenRecorder.m), I saw one line of code:

```
mCaptureScreenInput = [[NSClassFromString(@"QTCaptureScreenInput") alloc] init];
```

A google search for `QTCaptureScreenInput` reveals only two mentions on the web, that project and another one with an unused ivar of that type.

What is a `QTCaptureScreenInput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a private API. You can see [here](https://raw.github.com/gist/1015891/b71dbe5f2bf5d949c4c13cb5c4db959c4d9c8040/QuickTimePlayer.classdump.h) that QuickTime Player uses it to implement screen recording.

Comment: If you are targeting Lion, you can use [AVCaptureScreenInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureScreenInput_Class/) which is a public API.